# Regex multiple grouping

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I'm trying to make a program that organize my TV Show collection.

My regex need to recognize the episode number given the file name of the episode. Please note that sometimes a single video file contains more episodes.

In my particular case I only need to parse episodes named like:

"s01e01.avi"  expected result= 1

"s01e01 & s01e02.avi" expected result= 1, 2

"s01e01.02.avi" expected result= 1, 2

"s01e03.04 s01e05.06.avi" expected result= 3,4,5,6

"s01e03.04.05.06.avi" expected result= 3,4,5,6

```
final Matcher m = Pattern.compile("s[0-9]{1,2}e([0-9]{1,2})(\\.[0-9]{1,2})*").matcher(fileName);
while(m.find()) {
    for (int i = 1; i < m.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("myEpisodeNumer = " + m.group(i));
    }
}
```

That's what I've got, but it works only in the case where there's a single episode per group:

WORKS

"s01e01.avi" result: 1, correct

"s01e01 & s01e02.avi" result: 1, 2,  correct

DON'T WORK

"s01e01.02.avi" (Only matches the first occurrence, 1 in this case) expected result: 1,2

"s01e01.02 s01e03.04.avi" (Only matches the first occurrence for each group, 1 and 3 in this case)expected result: 1,2,3,4

Thanks a lot for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a single regex can't easily return a list of values.  (Even if you put `*` or `+` after a capture group, this does not cause more capture groups to be added; the number of capture groups is a fixed value based on the pattern only, not on the source string.)

So while you did well to write a loop to find each portion beginning with `s`, you still have the problem that the portions beginning with `s` may *themselves* contain lists of episode numbers.  While you may be able to find a tricky way to do this with a single loop, I'd recommend using a nested `find` loop, or `split`.  Your first pattern should look like this:

```
final Matcher m = Pattern.compile("s[0-9]{1,2}e([0-9]{1,2}(?:\\.[0-9]{1,2})*)").matcher(fileName);
```

Note that the part that matches multiple occurrences of things like `.02`, `.03`, etc., has been moved inside the first capture group.  (I put `?:` in the second set of parentheses to emphasize the fact that this is **not** a capture group that you will be extracting with `group()`.)  After you do that, the result of `group(1)` could be `"01"` or `"01.02"` or `"03.04.05"` or whatever.  Now you can split on the period character:

```
while (m.find()) {
    for (String episode : m.group(1).split("\\.")) {
        System.out.println("myEpisode = " + episode);
    }
}
```

**P.S.** This is an approach that will work generally on similar kinds of problems.  Your particular problem is simple enough to solve with a single loop (because the combination `.\d\d` doesn't occur anywhere else except inside one of the `s\d\de.......` patterns), but there will be situations where that approach won't work.

Answer (score 3):

try this: (didn't adjust to fit java syntax)

```
(?<=s\d\de)(\d\d)|(?<=\d\d[.])(\d\d)*
```

example here: see the captured groups:

http://regex101.com/r/jH3yZ5/4

Comment: You are basically using the same regex as mine... And I don't know why, but it don't work... try something like s01e01.02.03

Comment: @Spotlight ok, you didn't put that in example, I would think about it now, so you have `sxxexx.xx.xx.xx.xx ...(n) parts` but I don't think this deserve a downvote.. :-(

Answer (score 2):

Why not just

```
e(\d\d)\.?(\d\d)?
```

As long as you don't have any TV shows named "The55 show" or similar, it's not going to break. The episode numbers will be captured in the groups of the match.

[See it in action here](http://fiddle.re/9bjbm).

Comment: the thing is, OP has `s01e03.04` read the question twice pls.

Comment: @Kent Fixed. There's still no need to match the `s...` portion.

Comment: The problem is that if you "legally acquire" a Episode, the name is really messed up, so I want a regex more accurrate as possible: many times i see something like "s01e03 by P0se1don.avi" (the e1 inside Poseidon is gonna break the regex)